# php - how to find text in a string from database?

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say i have:

```
$title = "Rihanna - Man Down";
```

and a database multiple rows including one with a field called "name" with the "Rihanna" value

now... how can i check if in $title exists "Rihanna" and if it does how to add a link on "Rihanna" like this:

with other words check if one of the expresions from $title exists the database

- i think this second formulation it is better

> ```
> <a href="artist?id=Rihanna">Rihanna</a> - Man Down
> ```

I want to do something like youtube does at some of it;s music videos to be more clear

Comment: Please rephrase your question it's a bit tough to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$words = explode("-", $title);
$result = array();

foreach ($words as $word)
{
    $word = trim($word);
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM table WHERE name='" . mysql_real_escape_string($word) . "'");

    if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0)
    {
        $result[] = '<a href="artist?id=' . $word . '">' . $word . '</a>';
    }
    else
    {
        $result[] = $word;
    }
}

$result = implode($result, " - ");
```

This will however also link to "artist?id=Pink" if a song from another artist is named Pink, but you have the artist Pink in your database.

Comment: i've tried this but i have this error: "Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given" on the line with `if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0)`

Comment: @m3tsys then start debugging. Probably there's an error in the query. Enable error reporting, print the query.

Comment: error reporting is on: i get the same error ; when i echo $result i get - sign

Comment: @m3tsys I accidentally swapped the parameters for `explode()`. Should work now.

Comment: thanks a lot! that worked... now i have a question...                                                               Let's say `$title = "justin bieber will be father";`   is there posible to do the same thing ?  i mean to work with or without that - sign?

Comment: @m3tsys no, it splits on dash (-), so if there's no dash, it will try to find the whole string.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correct, this can do the work:

Then first search in DataBase, your query must be something like this:

//Search for word in DataBase on filed "name"

```
$title = "Rihanna - Man Down";
$arr = explode('-', $title); 
$title = $arr[0];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($title) . "%'");
```

//If find results, then we replace and generate links in this loop

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    $str = str_replace($title, '<a href="artist?id='.$title.'">'.$title.'</a>', $row['name']);
    echo $str; //<a href="artist?id=Rihanna">Rihanna</a> - Man Down
}
```

Comment: thank you, this works but that was just an example...  i need to check if a word from $title exists in the dataabse and put a link on that word if it exists. please think at the youtube example.

Comment: Look at modified answer, try this.

Comment: thanks, this really works ; but it works when `$title = "Rihanna";`  ; when `$title = "Rihanna - Man Down";` (or with other words, when it contains something more than the artist name it doesn't work)

Comment: If your Artist is always first word of $title, then you can use this:

`$arr = explode(' ', $title);
$title = $arr[0];`

Comment: Or this is better:
`$arr = explode('-', $title); $title = $arr[0];`

Comment: Look at whole code in my answer, there is no reason to NOT work :)

Answer (score 1):

Split your title into words, and for each word check if your database contains row with that name. If yes, replace occurences of the word with link.

```
foreach (preg_split("/\s+/", $title) as $word) {
    if (word_in_database($word)) {
        $title = str_replace($word, "<a href=\"artist?id=$word\">$word</a>", $title);
    }
}
```